# Mask middle 6 digits of credit card number in logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

The requirement is to show the start 6 digits and last 4 digits and mask the remaining numbers of credit card in logstash. I applied gsub/mutate filter but the replacement string doesn't allow regex. Any other way this can be done in logstash?

```
if [message] =~ '\d{16}' {
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message", "\d{6}\d{4}\d{4}", "\d{6}######\d{4}"]
        add_tag => "Masked CardNo"
    }
}
```

This code masks the credit card 3456902345871092 to \d{6}######\d{4} but it should be masked as 345690######1092.

As an alternative, if possible even displaying only the first 6 digits or the last 4 digits of the card would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't mask the data before you send it to Logstash?

Comment: The field containing this card number is a free text field and hence not able to mask the data before in fluentd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capturing groups in the regex and use those group in the replacement part: this regex `(\d{6})(\d{6})(\d{4})`, when matched, creates three groups ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/m0aoOx/1)). This groups can be used in the replacement string: `\1######\3` this string will use the first and third replacement groups.

So in your case, your configuration should look like this:

```
mutate {
    gsub => ["message", "(\d{6})(\d{6})(\d{4})", "\1######\3"]
    add_tag => "Masked CardNo"
}
```

Also, your regex `\d{6}\d{4}\d{4}` is wrong to match a 16-number credit card number, the second `\d` needs to grab 6 characters.