# Mask a part of creditcard number using logstash grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Trying to mask out a part (6-10th digit) of the 16 digit credit card.

`1234567898763456` to `123456######3456`

I can think of using gsub filter, but I can't find a way to match the exact section of numbers.

The option would be to split in various sections and then gsub the whole field to '#' and then join back, seems too much work. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Below example would mask all characters, how do I mask selective pattern, from 6th to 10th digit, to get a result like `123456######3456`.

```
filter
{
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message","[0-9]{16}","################"   
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This question had been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433254/mask-middle-6-digits-of-credit-card-number-in-logstash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filter {
    mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message","([0-9]{6})([0-9]{6})([0-9]{4})", "\1######\3"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how the code answers the question improves its long-term value. It also helps avoid having your answer down-voted or flagged as low quality. See [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).