# Mask name in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, mask, logstash-grok, elk

**hi guys, is there any solution to mask the name in logstash string message?**

I didn't find any solution on the internet and in any elasticsearch topic or document, has anyone tried this?

Comment: This post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433254/mask-middle-6-digits-of-credit-card-number-in-logstash

Comment: this post you sent me is masking a pattern, I wanted to mask something that there is no pattern